# Worklight Appcenter console giving error

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-appcenter

We were trying to access a deployable file(.apk,.ipa) from Worklight appcenter console in order to update a new version of an app, but it threw the below error. we noticed that the same is happening with all apps and not just with any particular app.

Please note that it was working fine before. However because of a certain issue,we had to update liberty profile(8.5.5.9) recently. But not very sure if that is creating the problem or anything else.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
[7/25/16 16:25:19:590 SGT] 000000ac com.ibm.puremeap.services.DirectoryService                   E {
   "id": "72278944-b8c7-4faa-adfe-1716786a8a28",
   "message": "FWLAC0000E: A server error was detected.",
   "params": [
   ],
   "productVersion": "6.2.0.01-20151118-0709"
}
com.ibm.puremeap.resources.exceptions.SystemException
   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.FavoriteApplicationHelper.getAreFavoriteApplicationsForPrincipal(FavoriteApplicationHelper.java:413)
   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.DirectoryService.addFavoriteFlag(DirectoryService.java:450)
   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.DirectoryService.__retrieve2__(DirectoryService.java:430)
   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.DirectoryService.__retrieve__(DirectoryService.java:394)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceLocator(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:230)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:115)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1290)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:778)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:475)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:152)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:94)
   at com.ibm.puremeap.services.RestFilter.doFilter(RestFilter.java:60)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1021)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1143)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4869)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:471)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:405)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:285)
   at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:66)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
   at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.FavoriteApplicationHelper.areFavoriteApplicationsForPrincipal(FavoriteApplicationHelper.java:442)
   at com.ibm.puremeap.resources.data.impl.FavoriteApplicationHelper.getAreFavoriteApplicationsForPrincipal(FavoriteApplicationHelper.java:408)
   ... 83 more
```

Below are the environment details:

Worklight Version : 6.2.0.01-20151118-0709,
Liberty Profile   : 8.5.5.9,
OS                : Windows Server 2008,

Comment: Are you trying to access appcenter catalog and getting this error ?. Can you detail more on that. Updating it to liberty profile(8.5.5.9) should ideally not cause the problems.

Comment: We are getting error in application properties screen for all apps.

Answer (score 0):

See [PI24446](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI24446). You need to install the corresponding ifix. Best is to install the latest ifix of Worklight.

In general, this is a problem with the user who is logged in into the Application Center Console. The ifix should fix the problem, if not, then at least it will give you detailed exception messages in the log file about what is wrong. Typically the problem is a case mismatch of the login name of the user compared to the LDAP (if you are using LDAP). It could also be that application security in liberty is disabled and as consequence no user is logged in at all, which is not supported by the Application Center Console.

About application security, verify that server.xml contains <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>.

About how to configure application security in detail, see [the Knowledge Center about Liberty](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_configuring_websphere_applicat1.html).

Comment: Thanks Georg. verified server.xml , it contains both <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature> and <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>

Comment: I never had appSecurity-1.0 and appSecurity-2.0 in the same server.xml, hence I have no experience with this. I think appSecurity-2.0 needs additionally the servlet-3.0 feature in order to get web applications secure. Indeed I have one liberty just using appSecurity-1.0, and another liberty that has appSecurity-2.0 plus servlet-3.0. I never tried other combinations.

Comment: See also http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feature_appSecurity-2.0.html. It is also a bit better explained in the beta documentation, see http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_superfeat.html

Comment: we updated to latest iFix(6.2.0.1-WEE-IF201605240631). Still the issue persists. Also there aren't any additional error messages. This error seems to be reproducable when we access this uri https://abc.xyz.com/applicationcenter/service/directory/iOS(or Android)/com.abc.xyz/1.0

Comment: we added a new application which was uploaded and after that everything seems to be working fine. We even tested after restarting the server and seems to work. this is strange.